# Insert / update in a mongodb array via meteor

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I try to save, out of a meteor app, the result of a vote per user in a mongodb. How ever for hours I have not been successful. Here is what I have:

A mongodb collection Decision:
Decision._id
Decision.votes[]

At the beginning all is empty.

In the app I generate the result and call on the server:

```
'updDecisionVote':function(id,userid,votum){
    Decision.update({_id:id,votes:[{user:userid,vote:votum}]});
}
```

But I constantly get an err 500 an no more information. If it is an update, I read that the record would be created if it is not there.

So I struggle a the point of inserting. The other interesting issue will be: this update updates the decision record. But if a users wants to change his vote will the above update cover this or will there just be a further record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 error means that the server got an erro, but the server dosnt know why.

so lets change that `Meteor.method` to look like this(do all the logic on the client side)

```
'updDecisionVote':function(id,userid,votum){
    Decision.update(id,userId,votum);
}
```

Also let use a callback on the `Meteor.call` to get more information of the error (if this exist), like this (using the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operator)

```
Meteor.call('upDecisionVote',this._id,{$push:{user:userId,vote:votum}},function(err,result){
  if(err){
    console.log(err.reason)
  }else{
   console.log("Vote Done")
  }
})
```

BTW, Why don't do that on the client side?, and create the correct `allow/deny` rules?

```
 Decision.update(this._id,{$push:{user:userId,vote:votum}});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use your example for further learning. Since I am not so experienced I took a very pragmatic approach. I have set up a new collection "votes" in which I placed all information of scope and just added a decisionID field to get a reference back. This is more the relational way but thinking of normalization this might not be the worst way. How ever the mongo schema design and query language is next to learn.